# Using randi in MATLAB to get random values: values are not distributed uniformly

Tags: matlab, random

I am generating a random population of strings made of 0s and 1s. I am using `randi(2)-1` to get a randomly generated single value 0 or 1. I expect to get 1s almost as frequently as 0s. Instead, when I view all the individuals in the population, they mostly consist of 1s. Below is the code - what is wrong?

```
for iInd=1:individualsCount
    individual(attrCount) = 0;

    for i=1:attrCount
         individual(i) = randi(2)-1;
    end

    population{iInd} = individual;
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need a loop to generate a random string of 0's and 1's. Try this instead:

```
individual = randi([0 1],[attrCount,1]);
```

Secondly, again, you don't need a loop to construct your `population` cell. Try this instead:

```
population=arrayfun(@(x)randi([0 1],[attrCount,1]),1:individualsCount,'UniformOutput',false)
```

You might have to change the order of rows and columns depending on how you want to set it up.

---

Now, coming to your question, you ought to understand that these distributions are stochastic and approach a truly uniform distribution of 50% 1s and 50% 0s only as your sample size approaches infinity. If your `attrCount` is small enough, do not be surprised if you don't find numbers close to 50% for each. That doesn't mean it is wrong. It is what it is.

Here's how the distribution of 1s looks like for a random binary vector of different sample sizes. You can see that for small sample sizes, there is high variability (and by no means is this exact... it will be different each time), whereas as you start approaching large sample sizes of 1000 and above, your distribution of 1s gets closer and closer to 50%, eventually being exactly 50% at infinity.

[image]

Comment: As an aside: Note that due to the JIT compiler in recent Matlab releases, for loops are no longer as bad as they used to be.  Depending on the values of `attrCount` and `individualsCount`, the explicit for loop can be up to 4x faster than `arrayfun`.  Clearly, though, asking for a two-dimensional matrix (attrCount x individualsCount) from `randi` is the most efficient solution.

Comment: @MattB. I agree, the JIT compiler has made quite a few strides. I used MATLAB again a few months ago after a brief break, and I was shocked by how my friend's clumsy nested 4 for-loop solution was 2x faster than my "smart", compact and vectorized solution (which used to be way faster than loops in the past).